# How to keep track of videos watched with Node.js and Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm building a MEAN stack video app (I'm pretty new to Node and Mongodb) and I need a way to keep track of videos watched. How do I do this?

I was thinking I could have an array of Ids in the user collection that references videos but I'd like to be able to return videos with a `watched: true` key value pair that's dependent on the user making the request. If this is a good way to do it, how do I return a key value pair that's dependent on another document in another collection?

User model:

```
let UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    trim: true,
    unique: true,
    validate: {
        validator: VALUE => validator.isEmail(VALUE),
        message: '{VALUE} is not a valid email'
    }
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 6
},
admin: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
},
vid_inprogress: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
},
vid_completed: [{ type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Attachment' }],
tokens: [{
    access: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    token: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}]
});
```

Video Model:

```
var Video = mongoose.model('Video', {
url: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    trim: true
},
title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: '',
    trim: true
},
description: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true
},
img: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true
},
attachments: [{ type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Attachment' }]
});
```

`vid_completed` on the User model is where I'd like to keep track of the video ids that have been watched. And the Video model is what would be returned with a key: value pair based on whether the video id is found in the user `vid_completed` array. Let me know if that makes sense. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using an array in the User model like so:

```
vid_inprogress: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Video'
},
vid_completed: [{ type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Video' }]
```

I'll just have to add `watched: true` on the front end. Let me know if you have a better way. I'd be interested to hear.